# How to list all windows in Motif Window Manager?

Tags: linux, rhel, motif

I'm using mwm in rhel. I'm often lost when I have multiple windows. Is there anyway to list all the opened windows?

Google din't help!

Answer (score 3):

According to [an old version of Motif 2.0 User's Guide](https://sites.ualberta.ca/dept/chemeng/AIX-43/share/man/info/C/a_doc_lib/motif/motifug/toc.htm) [[Archived version](http://web.archive.org/web/20140331030731/http://csweb.cs.wfu.edu/%7Etorgerse/Kokua/Irix_6.5.21_doc_cd/usr/share/Insight/library/SGI_bookshelves/SGI_Developer/books/Motif21_UG/sgi_html/index.html)], the answer unfortunately seems to be: **no, there is no window list feature in Motif `mwm`.**

Apparently, an [up-to-date Motif 2.1 User's Guide](https://shop.opengroup.org/m021) would cost about $10 in PDF form.

`mwm` is now quite old and its feature set may be effectively frozen by standardization and requirement for legacy compatibility. Back when it was originally designed, computer performance levels were nowhere near the capabilities of modern systems, and perhaps nobody expected that someone would have wanted to have as many windows at the same time as a modern power user might.